# Loop through array for map

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need help looping through an array and finishing this code. My array is created from an XML file. The XML file contains meeting location data to be plotted on a map. The array ends up looking like this:

```
markerfilter[0].name
markerfilter[0].address
markerfilter[0].Meeting_Type
etc...
markerfilter[1].name
markerfilter[1].address
markerfilter[1].Meeting_Type
etc...
```

Right now all the markers plot on the map. I need to loop through the array and filter it based on some variables I setup. This is my attempt at looping through the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markerfilter.length; i++) {
    if (markerfilter[i].Meeting_Type==type&&markerfilter[i].Day_of_Meeting==day&&markerfilter[i].Time_of_Meeting==time){
        //need to plot the points on the map here
        }else{
        //need to show blank map
        }
    }
```

Here is my entire code. I don't even know if the loop is in the right place or if other pieces of the code need to go inside the loop. Any help??

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#map").css({
    height: 500,
    width: 600
});
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.653823, -79.382843);
MYMAP.init('#map', myLatLng, 11);

$("#showmarkers").click(function(e){
    MYMAP.placeMarkers('include/xml.php');
});
});

var MYMAP = {
map: null,
bounds: null
}

MYMAP.init = function(selector, latLng, zoom) {
var myOptions = {
    zoom:zoom,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
this.map = new google.maps.Map($(selector)[0], myOptions);
this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
}

var markerfilter = [];
MYMAP.placeMarkers = function(filename) {
$.get(filename, function(xml){
    $(xml).find("marker").each(function(){
        var name = $(this).find('name').text();
        var address = $(this).find('address').text();
        var address2 = $(this).find('address2').text();
        var Meeting_Type = $(this).find('Meeting_Type').text();
        var Time_of_Meeting = $(this).find('Time_of_Meeting').text();
        var Day_of_Meeting = $(this).find('Day_of_Meeting').text();
        var Open_Meeting = $(this).find('Open_Meeting').text();
        var Wheelchair = $(this).find('Wheelchair').text();
        var ASL = $(this).find('ASL').text();
        var Comments = $(this).find('Comments').text();
        // create a new LatLng point for the marker
        var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
        var lng = $(this).find('lng').text();
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng));

        var markerdata = {};
        $(this).children().each(function() {
            markerdata[this.tagName] = $(this).text();
        });
        markerfilter.push(markerdata);

        var MeetingType = document.getElementById("Meeting_Type");
        var type = MeetingType.options[MeetingType.selectedIndex].text;
        var DayofMeeting = document.getElementById("Day_of_Meeting");
        var day = DayofMeeting.options[DayofMeeting.selectedIndex].text;
        var TimeofMeeting = document.getElementById("Time_of_Meeting");
        var time = TimeofMeeting.options[TimeofMeeting.selectedIndex].text;

        for (var i = 0; i < markerfilter.length; i++) {
        if (markerfilter[i].Meeting_Type==type&&markerfilter[i].Day_of_Meeting==day&&markerfilter[i].Time_of_Meeting==time){
            markerfilter[i].setMap(MYMAP.map);
            }else{
            markerfilter[i].setMap(null);
            }
        }

        // extend the bounds to include the new point
        MYMAP.bounds.extend(point);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point,
            map: MYMAP.map
        });

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var html='<b><u>'+name+'</b></u><br />'+address2+'<br />'+address+'<br />'+Meeting_Type+',&nbsp'+Time_of_Meeting+',&nbsp'+Day_of_Meeting+'<br />Open Meeting:&nbsp'+Open_Meeting+'<br />Wheelchair Accessible:&nbsp'+Wheelchair+'<br />ASL:&nbsp'+ASL+'<br />Comments:&nbsp'+Comments;
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(MYMAP.map, marker);
        });
        MYMAP.map.fitBounds(MYMAP.bounds);
    });
});
console.log(markerfilter);
}
```

Right now when I run my current, firebug tells me:
markerfilter[i].setMap(null) is not a function.

Comment: And what happens with that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the error: **markerfilter[i].setMap(null) is not a function**, I think I see your problem. Within the `MYMAP.placemarkers` function, you create the `markerdata` object, define some kind of `tagName` property that is assigned a text value, and then push `markerdata` onto  :he `markerfilter` array:

```
var markerdata = {};
$(this).children().each(function() {
    markerdata[this.tagName] = $(this).text();
});
markerfilter.push(markerdata);
```

Then about 10 lines later, you have a `for` loop that attempts to retrieve what the code appears to expect will be markers from the `markerfilter` array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markerfilter.length; i++) {
    if ( markerfilter[i].Meeting_Type==type && 
            markerfilter[i].Day_of_Meeting==day && 
            markerfilter[i].Time_of_Meeting==time ) {

        markerfilter[i].setMap( MYMAP.map );
    }
    else {
        markerfilter[i].setMap( null );
    }
}
```

Since the `markerfilter` array has been loaded with `markerdata`, it doesn't contain markers, so it makes sense that `markerfilter[i].setMap(null)` is not a function, because `markerfilter[i]` isn't a marker. Hope this helps -

Comment: You were correct! I had to load the array with the marker object after the marker was created. Firebug helped greatly on this one!